# Webscraping certain websites does not work

Tags: web-scraping

I have a project where I want to collect data on betting odds in eSport so I want to scrape this website:
https://danskespil.dk/oddset/esport/counter-strike-go

But when I try to get the content from postman I don’t get all the content of the website, so some of it is unreachable. I was thinking that all websites must be scrabable or else Google could not crawl them right? Is there anything I could do different to get all the content from the provided website, would it help to use a library like scrapy?

Comment: Which language do you use? And yes, it would be easier if you use library to get all the html content. For example I am using cheerio for my web-scrapping project using javascript.

Comment: language can be whatever, but would prefer it to be javascript or python.

Comment: Then you can search about cheerio for javascript and beautifulsoup for pyhton.

Comment: I have tried using libraries, but i still dont have access to all the content on websites, it seems the content is protected.

Comment: the content of the web site is generated by javascript. The best way is to simulate the navigation via Selenium for example. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ or https://ropensci.org/tutorials/rselenium_tutorial/

Comment: I always go with Cheerio because it's lightweight, but may fall short if you're scraping a complex third-party website that does funky stuff with cookies, feature detection, etc.
or if your use-case involves triggering complex interactions to traverse a workflow (evaluate some JS in the browser or wait for AJAX calls to load some DOM nodes, etc). If that's the situation I would go with Puppeteer. My two cents.